# Heroku Symfony2 App Works but No CSS/JS/etc

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

I finally just got my Symfony2 app to work in Heroku except that it's not getting any CSS or JS. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Including `<head>` code from the `base.twig.html`

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Machine{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerfoundation/css/foundation.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/project/css/main.css') }}">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/project/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/project/js/script.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('bundles/project/favicon.ico') }}">

</head>
```

I noticed that it seems to be using `Symfony2` favicon and such. So it might be using the wrong directory somehow, or bundle, for the "web" view of things.

it's

```
Root >
    Web >
      bundles >
          bmatznerfoundation > ... 
          framework > (original symfony junk)
          project > (THE FILES I WANT)
      .htaccess
      app.php
      app_dev.php
      apple-touch-icon.png
      config.php
      favicon.ico (a Symfony icon)
      robots.txt
```

Comment: You may want to include some of your code, any logs or whatever..

Comment: I'm not sure what code to include. It works fine locally, the routing and controllers, as well as the accessing of the "view", but when uploaded to Heroku (via git), the `twig` pages do not seem to be getting the css/js. (edited original question with some code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, this is silly, in my `.gitignore` file, `/web/bundles` was there. I simply removed it, re-committed, then everything worked great!